# I want to link a div scrollbar to the main scrollbar in React - just like on the reddit website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, scrollbar, react-component

I want to link a div scrollbar to the main scrollbar in React - just like on the [reddit](https://reddit.com)

```js
function Body() {
  return (
    <div className="Body">
      <div className="user-menu"></div>

      <main className="timeline">
        <div className="post-box"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
        <div className="post"></div>
      </main>

      <div className="discover">
        <div className="discover-box"></div>
        <div className="footer-box"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

i want to link the main scrollbar to the one in the "main" element with id as timeline.

[image: here is a picture of the layout]